# Tensorboard callback with keras fit_generator, 'Function' has no attribute 'fetch_callbacks'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am trying to run a model using keras's `fit_generator` with a `tensorboard_callback` for profiling a specific epoch. I am running the following code for the generator:

```
def gen(source):
loopable = iter(source)
for batch in loopable:
    yield (batch[0], batch[1])
```

In the main training script I am instantiating the generator and using the model with a tensorboard callback as follows:

```
train_gen = gen(train_datasource)
log_dir="logs/profile/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 3)
m.fit_generator(train_gen, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=500, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=32, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

The main issue I am facing is that the training always halts with the error `'Function' has no attribute 'fetch_callbacks'` with the following stack trace:

```
m.fit_generator(train_gen, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=500, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=32, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 177, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 65, in on_epoch_begin
    callback.on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks_v1.py", line 386, in on_epoch_begin
    self.merged] = self._fetch_callback
AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'fetch_callbacks'
```

I am using tensorflow 1.15 also tried downgrading to 1.14 but still no success. I am trying to train with the tensorboard callback to debug the performance for a specific epoch other than the first one. But so far my attempts have failed to make the callback function correctly. I made sure the GPU is running and detected correctly too.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `tf.keras` fit function instead of fit generator and it worked correctly as expected:

`m.fit(x=train_gen, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=500, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=8, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])`